# How to extend layout?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-xml

I'm having trouble understanding why my extended layout isn't working. I made a class which goes

```
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {

        public MyLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    }
```

I wrote the XML as

```
<package.MyLayout

. . .

</package.MyLayout>
```

The method where I get the error is in the activity where I have called setContentView(R.layout.layout_relative).

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong because surely you inflate in the activity from the XML layout which is building on the custom class where I can make my overrides?

Comment: Could you post the error?

Answer (score 0):

you need the other constructor, the one that takes two parameters:

```
public MyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
}
```

which is used when the layout is inflated from the layout

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the wrong constructors!

Android xml inflation uses

- `public RelativeLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int
  defStyleAttr)`
- `public RelativeLayout (Context context, AttributeSet
  attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)` since api 21